# How to set and clear custom errors - React Hook Form & Zod

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

How can I make it so that I'm able to programmatically clear errors for a form field only if I want, otherwise it should not cause an error on form submission.

Since the default zod validation doesn't seem to have a provision for this, I want to implement custom errors.

For example, i want a situation where if an option has been selected from the 'mode of payment' options in the select component, e.g., 'Mpesa Paybill', then error validation is present for only that particular field, otherwise it's turned off.

Code:

FormSchema:

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  modeOfPayment: z.string().nonempty({ message: "Please select an option" }),
  tillNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(8, { message: "Please enter a valid till number" }),
  paybillNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(8, { message: "Please enter a valid paybill number" }),
  accountNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(20, { message: "Please enter a valid account number" })
});
```

Mode of payment:

```
          <div>
            <h2>
              Mode of Payment
              <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
            </h2>
            <select
              {...register("modeOfPayment", {
                onChange: (e) => {
                  console.log("MODEOFPAYMENT EVENT", e);
                  setSelectedPaymentMode(e.target.value);
                },
              })}
              className={
              /* ... */
}
            >
              <option value="" disabled={true}>
                Choose a mode of payment
              </option>
              <option value="Mpesa Buy Goods">Mpesa Buy Goods</option>
              <option value="Mpesa Paybill">Mpesa Paybill</option>
            </select>
            {errors?.modeOfPayment?.message && (
              <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1">
                {errors.modeOfPayment.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
```

Mpesa Buy Goods option:

```
          {selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Buy Goods" && (
            <div>
              <h2>
                Enter till number
                <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
              </h2>
              <input
                {...restTillNumber}
                ref={(e) => {
                  tillNoRef(e);
                  tillNumberRef.current = e;
                  console.log("ref event (tillNumber): ", e);
                }}
                type="text"
                className={
                /* ... */
}
              />
              {errors?.tillNumber?.message && (
                <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1">
                  {errors.tillNumber.message}
                </p>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
```

Mpesa Paybill option

```
{selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Paybill" && (
            <div>
              <div className="mb-2">
                <h2>
                  Enter Paybill number
                  <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
                </h2>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...restPaybillNumber}
                  ref={(e) => {
                    paybillNoRef(e);
                    paybillNumberRef.current = e;
                    console.log("ref event (paybillNumber): ", e);
                  }}
                  className={
                  /* ... */
}
                />
                {/* {errors?.paybillNumber?.message && (
                  <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">
                    {errors.paybillNumber.message}
                  </p>
                )} */}
              </div>
              <div>
                <h2>
                  Account number
                  <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
                </h2>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...restAccountNumber}
                  ref={(e) => {
                    accountNoRef(e);
                    accountNumberRef.current = e;
                  }}
                  className={`h-8 w-11/12 self-center text-sm text-gray-800 ${
                    errors?.accountNumber?.message
                      ? "border-red-700 focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-700 focus:ring-2"
                      : "focus:border-none focus:ring focus:ring-emerald-700 focus:ring-2"
                  }`}
                />
                {errors?.accountNumber?.message && (
                  <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">
                    {errors.accountNumber.message}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the situation just like that

1. You have a form and a schema validator with Zod
2. You want to control error (add and remove) programmatically.

**The answer below, is not a plug-and-play solution, I'll just write down the possible ways to doing it.**

First of all, most of the schema validators support custom validation via functions, even asynchronous validations. So if your decision is based on asynchronous call or something that can be composed in a function, using a custom validation function is much better than adding a ton of logic out of the schema
And [This](https://zod.dev/?id=asynchronous-refinements) is a topic of how to do it in Zod, from thier documentation.
And there is another type of validation called *Conditional Validation*, you can decide to use this too, if it will come up with your situation.

---

Otherwise, we have a work around using useForm, but first things first we need to know somethings about useForm.

we have two function exported from *useForm* for manipulating custom errors, the first one is [`addError`](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/seterror/) and the second one is [`clearErrors`](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/clearerrors/).
And another function that uses for trigger validation action called [`trigger`](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger/).

that is how formProps.handleSubmit works

1. clearErrors()
2. trigger()
3. looping over the output of validation result and doing addError(fieldName, {...props})

For your situation you can come up with that

1. Define your schema with Zod and exclude the field that you want to validate it custom.
2. Change the type of button from `submit` to `button` and add a handler to it
3. In the handler:

   - clearErrors()
   - trigger()
   - do your custom validation
   - loop over both validation result and use addError.
   - if there wasn't any error, do what you want to do by the data.

**Hope this will help, and if there is anything cloudy, just tell me.**